# Library Installation Uses Python 2, Needs to use Python 3

Tags: python, python-3.x

In order to install [auto-sklearn](https://automl.github.io/auto-sklearn/stable/installation.html#installation), I have installed Python3 (which is a requirement) via `Homebrew`.  I have aliased the Python version in my `.bash_profile` as `alias python='python3'` such that the following is true:

```
$python -V
>> Python 3.6.1
```

But when I `curl` the dependencies, I get the following error:

`Command "/usr/local/opt/python/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools,` `tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/46/rh_gbvxn2q19xbn10grfz3r00000gn/T/pip-build-VBNFhl/pyrfr/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /var/folders/46/rh_gbvxn2q19xbn10grfz3r00000gn/T/pip-q9LGfp-record/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in /private/var/folders/46/rh_gbvxn2q19xbn10grfz3r00000gn/T/pip-build-VBNFhl/pyrfr/`

Which clearly indicates that it is trying to use Python2.7 to execute an installation command.  How do I force my system to execute that command with Python3?

Comment: why are you using `curl` instead of `pip`?

Comment: you first have to `curl` down all deps, then use `pip` to install the library

Comment: @MadPhysicist did you look at the documentation? 

"Please install all dependencies manually with:"

then 

"Then install auto-sklearn:"

Comment: i dont understand what the disagreement here is.  it's a 2 step processes, which it sounds like we agree on

Comment: @redress. I think you're right. Could you post the commands you actually ran just for completeness?

Comment: `sudo curl https://raw.githubusercontent.com/automl/auto-sklearn/master/requirements.txt | xargs -n 1 -L 1 pip install --no-cache-dir --force-reinstall -I --no-deps --upgrade`

Then

`pip install auto-sklearn`

Comment: in your question please.

Comment: I think @phd is right BTW, you need to alias pip as well as Python if you did it by hand.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Ive also tried `pip3` which runs into permission issues when it tries to access Python2 distribution libraries

Comment: what is the exact alias?

Comment: Show how you aliased Python as well, while you are editing the question.

Comment: `alias python='python3'`

Answer (score 2):

Try `pip3 install` or  `python3.6 -m pip install`.